# How to define setOnTouchListener for multiple buttons in Android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with multiple buttons. For each button I created a `setOnTouchListener`, such as the code below.

```
Button btnOne = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_one);
Button btnTwo = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_two);

btnOne.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        myMethod(btnOne);
        return false;
    }
});

btnTwo.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        myMethod(btnTwo);
        return false;
    }
});
```

How could I create a generic method `setOnTouchListener` to use in all buttons? I'd like to have something like this:

```
btnOne.method();
btnTwo.method();
btnThree.method();
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using inner anonymous class objects which implements the interface `View.OnTouchListener`.

If I were you, better implement the interface in the `Fragment` (or other independent outer class):

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener {

    (...)

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return myMethod(v);
    }

    (...)

}
```

And define `myMethod` with argument `View v`. You can distinguish buttons with each `View` object's `id` (that has already been mentioned in Emanuel Moecklin's answer).

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener {

    (...)

    private boolean myMethod(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_one:
            (...)
            return true;
        case R.id.button_two:
            (...)
            return true;
        case R.id.button_three:
            (...)
            return true;

        (...)

        default:
            return false;
        }
    }

    (...)

}
```

Finally, you can set the same `OnTouchListener` object for multiple buttons quite smartly.

```
Button btnOne = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_one);
Button btnTwo = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_two);

btnOne.setOnTouchListener(this);
btnTwo.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same OnTouchListener and distinguish between the different views by using view.getId():

```
View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button_one) {
            // do your thing
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.button_two) {
            // do your thing
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Since you seem to call the same method myMethod(Button) for both buttons you could make this even shorter:

```
View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        myMethod(v);
        return false;
    }
};
```

myMethod can safely cast the View v to a Button object ((Button)v) to work with Button specific objects.

Please note that you should probably return true not false in onTouch to consume the touch event.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method that returns a `View.OnTouchListener` and pass that object into the parameters for `setOnTouchListener`.

```
btnTwo.setOnTouchListener(getTouchListener());

public View.OnTouchListener getTouchListener() {
    return new View.OnTouchListener() { ... } 
}
```