# How to change from onClick to onTouch method?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating music app and I need a change from onClick to the onTouch method so I can listen the sound at the moment I press the button and not only when release it. I can't figure out clearly what I need to add and change.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private SoundPool mSoundPool;
    private int btn2;
    private int btn5;
    private int btn13;
    private int btn14;
    private int btn15;
    private int btn16;
    private int btn17;
    private int btn18;
    private int btn19;
    private int btn20;
    private int btn21;
    private int btn22;



    private float LEFT_VOL = 1.0f;
    private float RIGHT_VOL = 1.0f;
    private int PRIORITY = 1;
    private int LOOP = 0;
    private float RATE = 1.0f;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        mSoundPool = new SoundPool(24, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
        btn2 = mSoundPool.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.r,1);
        btn5 = mSoundPool.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.g,1);
        btn13 = mSoundPool.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.k,1);
        btn14 = mSoundPool.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.hat,1);
        btn15 = mSoundPool.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.s,1);
        btn16 = mSoundPool.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.a,1);
        btn17 = mSoundPool.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.d,1);
        btn18 = mSoundPool.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.c,1);
        btn19 = mSoundPool.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.f,1);
        btn20 = mSoundPool.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.e,1);
        btn21 = mSoundPool.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.h,1);
        btn22 = mSoundPool.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.b,1);


    }


    public void playC(View v){
        mSoundPool.play(btn2,1,1,0,0,1);
    }

    public void playD(View v){
        mSoundPool.play(btn5,1,1,0,0,1);
    }

    public void playE(View v){
        mSoundPool.play(btn13,1,1,0,0,1);
    }

    public void playF(View v){
        mSoundPool.play(btn14,1,1,0,0,1);
    }

    public void playG(View v){
        mSoundPool.play(btn15,1,1,0,0,1);
    }

    public void playA(View v){
        mSoundPool.play(btn16,1,1,0,0,1);
    }

    public void playB(View v){
        mSoundPool.play(btn17,1,1,0,0,1);
    }

    public void playCC(View v){
        mSoundPool.play(btn18,1,1,0,0,1);
    }

    public void playCS(View v){
        mSoundPool.play(btn19,1,1,0,0,1);
    }

    public void playDS(View v){
        mSoundPool.play(btn20,1,1,0,0,1);
    }

    public void playFS(View v){
        mSoundPool.play(btn21,1,1,0,0,1);
    }

    public void playGS(View v){
        mSoundPool.play(btn22,1,1,0,0,1);
    }
```

**Activity_Main XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn22"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:onClick="playGS" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn21"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:onClick="playFS" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn20"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:onClick="playDS" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn19"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:onClick="playCS" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn18"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:onClick="playCC" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn17"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:onClick="playB" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn16"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:onClick="playA" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn15"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:onClick="playG"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn14"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:onClick="playF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn13"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:onClick="playE" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Small"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:onClick="playC" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:onClick="playD" />
```

I tried follow a lot of examples from internet but has always ended not effective.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you remove the JavaScript tag since the question is about Java/Android?

Comment: You will need to post your res/layout/activity_main.xml as well

Comment: Done sir. @JacobNordfalk

Comment: Why you want to change? If you have any good reason then better to remove `onClick` from XML and define `onTouchListener` for all button.

Comment: @PratikButani Because I want to play the sound at the moment I press button and not only when release it, onClick doesn't allow me do that. I tried what you suggested but now shows that android:onTouchListener is an unknown attribute.

Comment: @Kalachakra you have to define in Java code

Comment: @PratikButani Could you write some example on my code, where I should write and what?

Comment: @Kalachakra https://stackoverflow.com/a/31946984/1318946

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Remove the android:onClick attributes so

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn5"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:onClick="playD" />
```

becomes

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn5"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
```

Step 2: In the end of onCreate() method (just after btn22 = mSoundPool.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.b,1); and just before the closing }) insert this code

```
findViewById(R.id.btn5).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) playD(v);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Try it out with one of the buttons first, when it works proceed to the next buttons.

There are a lot of other ways of doing it, for example you could remove the method

```
public void playD(View v){
    mSoundPool.play(btn5,1,1,0,0,1);
}
```

and instead have this in onCreate():

```
findViewById(R.id.btn5).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) mSoundPool.play(btn5,1,1,0,0,1);
        return false;
    }
});
```

@Pratik_Butani pointed at [How to define setOnTouchListener for multiple buttons in Android fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31946268/how-to-define-setontouchlistener-for-multiple-buttons-in-android-fragment) which are a little more complicated but will be fine to look at when you get a little more understanding, later on.

Comment: Nice, I used first way and it works! But now I'm facing another issue relatively with endless sound loop spam while button is pressed and when I release button stills play the sound fx again. My goal is play 1 time per touch.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getAction() . To check if this i press down, move or release action you need to add: if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN). 
(BTW if you want help in the future you should accept the answer, so people can see that you value their help)